# rails memcached dalli Marshalling error for key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, rails-engines, dalli

I have such action in my controller:

```
def my
  @user = Ads::User.find current_user.id
  @postings = Rails.cache.fetch("@user.postings.includes(:category)") do
    @postings = @user.postings.includes(:category)
  end
end
```

I'm trying to cache @postings and get such error:

```
Marshalling error for key '@user.postings.includes(:category)': can't dump anonymous class #<Module:0x000000048f9040>
You are trying to cache a Ruby object which cannot be serialized to memcached.
```

If I try to cache @postings without includes there are no errors.
Can't figure out what is the problem.

You can find relevant models in the bottom:

```
module Ads
  class User < ::User
    has_many :postings, dependent: :destroy
  end
end

module Ads
  class Posting < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
    belongs_to :category
  end
end

module Ads
  class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :postings, dependent: :destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post the relevant models: User, Posting, Category.

Comment: I've added relevant models in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cache fetch code is all wrong.  The parameter to **fetch** is a string that identifies the data you want.  Your code is trying to use the same string for every user, so they would all see the same postings that would be saved by the first call of this method.

In my example below I used the user id and a string 'postings' to indicate all postings for a specific user.

It is incorrect to assign **@postings** inside the fetch block, the result of the block (the query result) is saved to **@postings**

Finally, ActiveRecord delays making the actual database call until absolutely necessary.  The **.all** call at the end of the query will return the data, and the data is what you want cached, not the configuration data used to create a query.

Here is the correct code:

```
@postings = Rails.cache.fetch("#{@user.id}:postings") do
    @user.postings.includes(:category).all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely complaining about this:

`class User < ::User`

Is there any reason why you're not using:

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: No, class User in in engine. So I'm just inheriting User from host app. Previous reply worked for me.