# can't dump anonymous class #<Module -error on caching in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting can't dump anonymous class error.

I have the following methods in my model.

```
 def seating_for(active)
   ln = cache(col("lu", active)) do
    self.seat_list_for(active).where(seat_id: self.seat_entries)
 end

 def seat_list_for(active)
   ex_id = Exc.id_by_symbol(active)
   self.row.exe.seats.where(ex_id: exc_id).first.seat_alloc_mem
 end
```

I am trying to cache ln. I am getting an error. Can't figure out what is the problem.

```
 can't dump anonymous class #<Module:0x00000007ab6088>
 /home/#/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@anon-ui/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/cache.rb:561:in `dump'
 /home/#/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@anon-ui/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/cache.rb:561:in `initialize'
 /home/#/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@anon-ui/gems/redis-activesupport-3.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:34:in `new'
 /home/#/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@anon-ui/gems/redis-activesupport-3.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:34:in `block in write'
 /home/#/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@anon-ui/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/cache.rb:520:in `instrument'
 /home/#/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@anon-ui/gems/redis-activesupport-3.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:33:in `write'
 /home/#/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@anon-ui/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/cache.rb:299:in `fetch'
 /home/#/user/projects/app/#/lib/lib_utility.rb:15:in `cache'
 /home/#/user/projects/app/#/app/models/smthng.rb:566:in `seating_for'
```

lib/lib_utility.rb

```
module LibUtility
  module ClassMethods
    def col(p, l)
     //smthng
    end

   def cache(l, options={}, &b)
     Rails.cache.fetch(l, expires_in: 50.minutes, &b)
   end
  end

  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.extend ClassMethods
  end

end
```

Needs guidance??

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14032855/832759

Comment: @j03w- ya.i saw that. but i m unable to find what mistake i ve done?? can you be more specific??

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11221230/687142 it explains how you should never cache an `ActivreRecord::Relation`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confusion caching Active Record queries with  Rails.cache.fetch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218917/confusion-caching-active-record-queries-with-rails-cache-fetch)

Answer (score 18):

The problem is that you try to cache an `ActiveRecord` relation collection. That is not possible. If you want to cache the query, you need to make it an array first

```
def seating_for(active)
  cache(col("lu", active)) do
    self.seat_list_for(active).where(seat_id: self.seat_entries).to_a
  end
end
```